# Passing pointers to structures through recursion (maze solving)

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, structure, maze

Hey guys so I'm in an intro to computer c programming course at university and we're asked to do a maze solving assignment. I'm writing this piece of code to find the reachability and solution to the maze. I pass a structure `M` with all the maze elements into it and then use recursion to search the maze. When I call the function within itself I'm not sure what argument to pass because I keep getting an error when I try to pass the argument as `assign_reachability(&M)`. If you have any suggestions or any help I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

```
int
assign_reachability(maze_t *M){

    int x, y;

    x = M->XP;
    y = M->YP;

    if(M->maze[y][x].exit==EXIT){
        return 1;
    }
    if(M->maze[y][x].type==NOGO || M->maze[y][x].visit==VISIT){
        return 0;
    }
    M->maze[y][x].visit = VISIT;
    /* check not on top row */
    if(y!=0){
        M->YP = (y-1);
        if(assign_reachability(&M))
            M->maze[y][x].reach=REACHABLE;
        return 1;
    }
    /* check not on bottom row */
    if(y!=((M->nrows)-1)){
        M->YP = (y+1);
        if(assign_reachability(&M))
            M->maze[y][x].reach=REACHABLE;
        return 1;
    }
    /* check not on left side */
    if(x!=0){
        M->XP = (x-1);
        if(assign_reachability(&M))
            M->maze[y][x].reach=REACHABLE;
        return 1;
    }
    /* check not on right side */
    if(x!=((M->ncolumns)-1)){
        M->XP = (x+1);
        if(assign_reachability(&M))
            M->maze[y][x].reach=REACHABLE;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `M->maze[y][x].reach==REACHABLE;` is wrong.(no effect)

Comment: Woops thanks for that! @BLUEPIXY

Comment: Your compiler could probably have told you that you have a useless statement with no effect. C compilers unfortunately don't enable a whole lot of warnings by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I keep getting an error when I try to pass the argument as
>   `assign_reachability(&M)`

The type of `&M` is `maze_t**`, i.e an address of a pointer to `maze_t`. The function expect its argument to be of type `maze_t*`,so you should pass it like:

`assign_reachability(M)`

since `M` is already a pointer to `maze_t`

Comment: That worked. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `int`s, but the function return type is `void`.

Comment: Yeah sorry I must have copied the code before I changed that. Just fixed it in the question thanks.